# JavaScript scope of function in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I had this function:

```
function loadCollapse() {
  function collapseDetail() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle(500);
  }    

  //toggle the componenet with class summary  
  $("span.summary").unbind('click',collapseDetail);
  $("span.summary").click(collapseDetail);
}
```

This function is bound to the `ajaxComplete()` event, aka gets executed whenever all ajax requests finish. The weird thing is that the unbind does not work.

It only works when `collapseDetail()` is defined/moved outside of `loadCollapse()`. Why?

Is a function inside a function really re-defined everytime that function get's executed?

Are there any potential memory/performance problems arising from this that i need to worry about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you call the function, the `collapseDetail` function will be redefined, thus it will be a different function from the one you created last time. Since it's a different function, and not the one you bound to at the first call, the unbind won't have any effect, because this new `collapseDetail` function was never bound.

Example of one way to solve this:

```
function generateLoadCollapse() {
    var collapseDetail = function() {
        $(this).next().fadeToggle(500);
    };

    var loadCollapse = function() {
        $("span.summary").unbind('click',collapseDetail);
        $("span.summary").click(collapseDetail);
    };

    return loadCollapse;
}
```

Another way could be something like:

```
function generateLoadCollapse() {
    return (function() {
        this.collapseDetail = function() {
            $(this).next().fadeToggle(500);
        };

        $("span.summary").unbind('click',this.collapseDetail);
        $("span.summary").click(this.collapseDetail);
    })();
}
```

You could then assign the value returned from this function to what you previously had for `loadCollapse`:

```
loadCollapse = generateLoadCollapse();
```

Comment: Is there a way to circumvent this? like the static keyword would in other languages?

Comment: @GungFoo, there are many ways, depending on how you structured your code... But no, there is no `static` keyword.

Comment: I am glad that there are many ways. :) name 1 that keeps the function in its current scope but also static. D:

Comment: @GungFoo, you named one yourself, in the question... Move it outside, so it's the same function.

Comment: but what if i want/need a function to be member of the/a function?

Comment: @GungFoo, this is where how you structured your code is important... You could have a function that returns the `loadCollapse` function for example, and inside `loadCollapse`, you could define the `collapseDetail` function as a member with `this`. But again, you'd have to always be talking about the same `loadCollapse` function.

Comment: @GungFoo, I added a different example to the answer, using closures.

Comment: @GungFoo, and another, using `this`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17857/discussion-between-gung-foo-and-radu)